# I wrote a file downloader in python,can`t skip if Error 404

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a simple file downloader in python, which has to try and download all the files from this website (which are avaible) , i tried the try function but it didn`t work, please if someone has some advice on how could I skip the bad urls

```
import urllib2

for x in range(1, 20000):

url = "http://etutorium.ru//webinaryService//users/seminar@aktivcorp.com/archive/" + str(x) + "/seminar@aktivcorp.com" + str(x) + ".flv"           

file_name = None
u = None
f = None
meta = None
file_size = None
file_size_dl = None
block_sz = None
status = None

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

Comment: when you say it **didn't** work, it's better to show what exactly didn't work, ie. errors and stacktrace? Also, have a quick glance you haven't even used *TRY*  in your code, which leads people who wanted to help, couldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose your request in a try catch exception block.

```
try:
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    #do something with the exception
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    #do something else perhaps?
```